# What's the Pythonic way to initialize an array?

Tags: python

I often see arrays in Python 3 that are declared in either one of two ways:

```
foo[2, 2] = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

or...

```
foo[2][2] = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

I've tried using both of these in computationally-expensive tasks(i.e. Machine Learning) for gargantuan arrays, and they seem to have not much of a difference.

Is there a difference between the two, in terms of memory allocation and execution times for looping and such, when the lists are big?

Comment: You need to post the complete code.. Here we do not even know what `t` and `dense` are

Comment: `dense[ti, tj]` is the same as `dense[(ti, tj)]`, or `dense.__getitem__((ti, tj))`, i.e. get the item from`dense` corresponding to the tuple `(ti, tj)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it creates the tuple `(ti, tj)` and passes it to `dense.__getitem__()`. As to what that accomplishes, you will need to see the documentation and/or source for `dense`'s type.

Answer (score 1):

The code `dense[ti, tj]` calls `dense.__getitem__((ti, tj))`. The comma in this case constructs a tuple. This doesn't work with lists, but it could work with a dictionary if the keys are tuples.

```
>>> [1,2,3][1, 2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

>>> {(1, 2): 1}[1, 2]
1
```